# SVG runtime load library

Tags: actionscript-3

Does anyone know of a good SVG loading library? I need to dynamically load in an SVG at runtime and display it to the user.

I've found two older libs that seem to cover some use cases:

https://github.com/lucaslorentz/AS3SVGRenderer

https://code.google.com/archive/p/svgweb/

but I was wondering if anyone know's of any maintained libs?

Comment: Did you just copy my question here?

Comment: yes I want to help you if anyone know's

Comment: oh, I forgot to say you can read svg class for haxe, as you know it's very similar to as3 https://github.com/openfl/svg